# "UnHover" Moved Elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to move an element to a different position on the page when I click on it.  The element is in a "hovered" state because the cursor is over it when I click it.  When the element gets to it's new postion it retains it "hovered" state.  How can I clear it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about the **focus** state?  I would think your standard `mouseout` event would fire if the object moves out from under the mouse, or the mouse moves off of it.

Comment: He is talking about the 'sticky' hover state that most browsers leave on elements after you pull them from under the mouse's feet. In other words, we need a workaround for a browser bug.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use (note this is a plug-in, so should be placed outside your `$(document).ready()` statement):

```
(function($) {
/*
    UnHover function
*/
    $.fn.unhover = function(ev) {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('unhover').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('unhover');
            });
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Attach it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(a).click(function(){
        $(this).unhover();
        // other onclick code
        return false;
    });
});
```

The CSS needs `.unhover` to go with the declaration for the element's natural state, like this:

```
a, a.unhover { color:#fff; }
a:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far, so it gets a +1 from me, but it's way too ugly. I'll keep looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "state"?  If it's just the appearance/position of the element you should set this using the ':hover' psuedo **css** class:

```
 a { color:#fff; }
 a:hover {
    color: red;
    font-style:bold;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the element is moved:

```
$("#moved_element").mouseout();
```

Or maybe re-setting element's class using `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

A working method is to clone the element, remove it from the DOM, and then re-add it.

```
$(this).clone(true).appendTo($(this).parent()).end().end().remove();
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/leifparker/pen/ByWxOa

Answer (score 0):

Your unhover class needs to come after your hover state as the pseudo class will override it. The unhover class can stay on and when someone blurs the focus then it will remove the class again giving the impression it was always in an off-state during the link going elsewhere.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      $('ul.social-links').on('click', 'a', function(){
        $(this).addClass('unhover');
    }).on('blur, mouseout','a', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('unhover');
    });
</script>
```

Then your css needs to be in this order:

```
a {
   color: #202020;
   opacity: 1;
   background: url('img/icons/social.png') no-repeat 0 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
   color: #ff0000;
   opacity: 0.5;
   background: url('img/icons/social.png') no-repeat -100px 0;
}
a.unhover {
   opacity: 1;
   background: url('img/icons/social.png') no-repeat 0 0;
   color: #202020;
}
```